# Create-react app integration with django backend vs babel and webpack pipeline

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I've been trying to get up a react and django application. First, I had followed this set of videos here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c2NqDyxppU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=3. There was a bunch of commands that you can see in the description that needed to be run in as well as a lot of copy pasting configuration files.

Later, my friend told me that create-react-app existed and would set up everything needed with just one command. I tried it, and it worked really well. However, there were issues with connecting it to django. The files that came out of create-react-app were different to the ones shown in the video and when I tried searching it up, a few solutions said to use `npm run build` and pass the build folder into django.

Running a build takes quite a long time and it is not automatic as it was when I had the webpack and babel system. What am I supposed to do to configure create-react-app so that I can get it to update automatically and get it into django.

Some places said that I could edit the config files when I do `npm run eject`. There is a problem that the `package.json` files in the tutorial project and the create-react-app project are not the same. The thing that lets the webpack and babel project update is this snippet of code in the package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

I ejected my create-react-app project but create-react-app doesn't use webpack so I won't be able to use this. What do I do?